# @AutoWired without @Qualifier

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

If there are two beans of the same type but with different names. Will spring Autowire the bean based on the name without us adding @Qualifier on the variable? I saw in the documentation, "**As a fallback Spring uses the bean name as a default qualifier value**".

```
@Component
class A{
}

@Component
class B extends A{
}

class C{

    @AutoWired
    A a;

//Will a be of type class A, even without @Qualifier...?
}
```

Comment: The field in class `C` is of type `B` so there is no way it is ever going to put bean `A` in there, because that's not assignable to a variable of type `B`.

Comment: Right.... Did not think this through.. Assume it is of type A..

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `B` will get injected because there is an `A` and a `B` for Spring to choose from and only one of them matches what the `@Autowired` field is asking for (Class `B`, because `A` is not assignable to `B`).

However, if you had two `B`'s, you would have to qualify it or mark one of them as the primary.

For example, given this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public B example1() {
        return new B();
    }
    @Bean
    public B example2() {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Well, now you have two instances of `B`, with different names. You can fix this one of two ways:

**Qualify your Autowire**

Note that I'm using field injection here, you really should use constructor, I'm doing it to save space.

```
 @Component
public class SomeComponent {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("example1")
    private B b;

}
```

Or

**Mark A Bean as Primary**

Redefine the beans, marking one as `@Primary`

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary // <-------- NEW!
    public B example1() {
        return new B();
    }
    @Bean
    public B example2() {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

And then inject without needing to name it:

```
 @Component
public class SomeComponent {

    @Autowired  // (Will pick Primary)
    private B b;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> If there are two beans of the same type but with different names. Will spring Autowire the bean based on the name without us adding @Qualifier on the variable?

`@Autowire` in the first place cares about type, later about the name. You will get exception saying that there are multiple candidates for injection while only 1 is expected.

`@Resource` on the other hand, cares about name first, type later.

Comment: So spring Autowired only looks at types and if there are two beans of the same type, it straight away throws an exception without even checking for name..? consider that I am not using Qualifier

Comment: Does not Autowired...
1.Matches by Type
2.Restricts by Qualifiers
3.Matches by Name

Comment: @pavan I didn't stated it "only looks at types". Its rather matter of precedence of matching. I will rephrase that as it can be understood that way indeed.

Comment: So going back to the example I gave in the question, Will 'a' have an instance of type 'A', without the qualifier?